# .htaccess - how to remove repeated characters from url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, repeat, duplicates

I have the following url:

```
example.com/hellllllllllo
```

And I was looking for a way to avoid repeated characters up to double.

Inspired by this question/answers [Remove Characters from URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess) I have created the following htaccess document to avoid repeated characters. If the character is repeated more than 23 times the url is not completely rewrited and I was wondering if there is any possible improvment?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)l{3,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1ll%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Use lazy matching: `^(.*?)l{3,}(.*)$`

Comment: It is what I am doing but surprisingly it is limited to 23 characters

Comment: You're using greedy match `(.*)`, lazy match is: `(.*?)`

Comment: Right! I need to change glasses. It works perfectly. Is there any optimization issue if I do it with every letters?

Comment: Check this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532/1190388

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my full answer to avoid repeated characters in urls using lazy match as suggested by samurai8 in previous comments:

**FOR REPEATED SLASHS AND DASHES**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(-{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1-%3 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(_{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1_%3 [R=301,L]
```

**FOR REPEATED LETTERS IN WORDS**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)a{3,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1aa%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)b{3,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1bb%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)c{3,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1cc%2 [R=301,L]
.
.
.
```