# Remove double slash at the begining of URL path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Due to moving of a site, the old hoster created a redirect to the new location. However, there is a leading slash `/` in the redirection and the former hoster is not able/willing to fix it. So I end up with all the redirects coming in like this:

`http://sub.domain.com//path/to/file.html`

So I tried to remove the leading slash:

- using `mod_alias`

  ```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^//(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com/$1
  ```
- using `mod_rewrite`

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
  RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
  ```

Neither works. The latter removes multiple slashes inside the path, but not at the beginning.

There are already questions regarding slash removing, but they don't solve this problem:

- [Issue In Removing Double Or More Slashes From URL By .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080652/issue-in-removing-double-or-more-slashes-from-url-by-htaccess)
- [.htaccess - how to remove repeated characters from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439437/htaccess-how-to-remove-repeated-characters-from-url/19472215#19472215)

Does Apache somehow treat this case differently?

How do I get rid of one of the leading slashes?

Answer (score 4):

#### The Problem

The point is that Apache 2 do not include leading slashes in the Requested URI, so you can't do this:

```
RewriteRule ^/+(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

or that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/+(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

what workes grat for any other kind of redirects or rewrites.

#### The Solution

But what you can do is to use the **the** Apache **request** variable that usually looks something like this: 
`GET /some-page HTTP/1.1`

With this in mind we can do the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s//+(.*)\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

So all leading slashes will be reduced to the one that that we need.

*I tested this positive on apache 2.4*

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score -2):

**The First `/` is Implied**

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.+) $1 [R=301,L,B,NE]
```

**Why?**

To match two slashes at the beginning of the path, in `htaccess`, we don't need to look for two slashes—just one—because the first slash is assumed. For instance, if you wanted to match `example.com/pasta`, your match rule would be `^pasta$`, not `^/pasta` (which would only match on `example.com//pasta`).

This is different from `httpd.conf`, where you would need to specify both slashes.

Confusing, but that's how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work... It's a bit frustrating because I don't have access to the access log... It still does not remove the leading slash. And it's not just a browser thing, `curl` shows that no redirection happens...