# How can I remove double slashes in my website URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

my website URL accept double slashes too. for example when I put `https://www.jamalacademy.com/class/9th-class` it accept then if i put 
`https://www.jamalacademy.com//class/9th-class` or `https://www.jamalacademy.com///class/9th-class`  it accept too.. even if i add so many slashes it accept too..

Help me to get ride of this problem.
my current htaccess file is like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)//+(.*)$ https://www.jamalacademy.com/$1/$2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //+
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^class/(.*)/?$ classes_list.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not tag spam. This has nothing to do with PHP or HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess - how to remove repeated characters from url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439437/htaccess-how-to-remove-repeated-characters-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove multiple slashes from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]    

RewriteRule ^class/(.*?)/?$ classes_list.php?get_page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.