# Aphace .htaccess Routing Assistance

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following routing options enabled on my .htaccess file. I want to route everything to the index.php file, yet am expriencing a challenge, because I have a foward slash - '/' being dropped in the process of routing. I need it for me to be able to identify unprovided/empty parameters at URL splitting level.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

A request like:
localhost/example/public/controller/method/var1/var2//var4

*will be routed as:*
localhost/example/public/controller/method/var1/var2/var4
*An empty var3 was dropped*
```

I will appreciate that support. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the additional slashes get removed in the querystring; so when you move them from being part of the URL to being the `url` parameter on the querystring...

You can avoid this by looking at the `REQUEST_URI` in the receiving script rather than a `$_GET['url']` parameter:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then in **index.php** instead of something like:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

... you'd need:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

---

*However*, with `REQUEST_URI` you'll get the full path, not just the path after your `RewriteBase`. Simplest way to remove it would be with `str_replace` - something like:

```
$baseURL = '/example/public/';
$replaceCount = 1;
$url = str_replace($baseURL, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $replaceCount);
```

Put in the `$replaceCount` *just in case* you happen to have variables `example/public` in the URL - it ensures only the first instance will be replaced.

Comment: This works for me, its easy to follow-through and implement.

Comment: @RPJr. No worries ;) I noticed it caused some quirks with the `RewriteBase` since you'll get the full path in the `REQUEST_URI` rather than just the path after `example/public` - but if you've worked around that already I'll leave the answer as-is.

Comment: the approach i took with the `RewriteBase` was to unset its values within  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`  before passing the rest as parameters. I would appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: @RPJr. - yeah, a simple string replacement before parsing `$url` would be easiest (and more efficient than `preg_replace()`) - I've updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, i meant to say first I had to explode the  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` i.e  `$parameters = explode('/',$url );`then unset the first two pockets that have the values example and domain before passing the rest as parameter.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)(/{2,})(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%3 [R=301,L]
```

It will replace all double slashes with a single one.

[See this post for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439437/htaccess-how-to-remove-repeated-characters-from-url/19472215#19472215)

Comment: Multiple slashes will be replaced anyway... I think he's trying to keep them to denote an empty var