# Remove dot from url via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site that has mode rewrite. The problem is that when in the rewrited url there is a dot, it leads to 404. I tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess) post

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/cart/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=cart&$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&subId=$3&id=$4&name=$5 [L,PT]    
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&subId=$3&name=$4 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&name=$3 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&name=$2 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=$1 [L,PT]
```

But it still gives me 404's. My goal is when i have dot in the url, to permanently redirect to same url without dot.

How can i acheive this?

**EDIT:**

I edited my file with this combination to exclude all the images, but it seems first condition doesn't apply:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^page/cart/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=cart&$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&subId=$3&id=$4&name=$5 [L,PT]    
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&subId=$3&name=$4 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&catId=$2&name=$3 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)?/([^.]+)?/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=$1&name=$2 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^page/([^./]+)/?$ ./index.php?page=$1 [L,PT]
```

**EDIT 2:**
I found my mistake.
First row should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ [NC]` instead `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ [NC]`

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `^(.*).(.*)$` with `^(.*)[.](.*)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `.`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

The `.` character is reserved in regex to mean "any character that isn't a newline".

Comment: Thanks. How can i exclude the images and media files from this rule?

Comment: @bksi Add this right before it: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|png|jpe?g|)$ [NC]` and whatever other extensions you don't want to have affected