# Removing special characters from query string in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've come across similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess), and found similar instructions on [mod_rewrite tutorials](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString).

I've determined that I need something along the lines of

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)<(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)>(.*)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301]
```

This works for `http://domain.com/<>`, but it does *not* work for `http://domain.com?a=<>`

I've also added the following, in my attempts to remove these characters from the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)<(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)>(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=301]
```

This did not change anything. I've also tried escaping < and > in the regex as well (i.e. `^(.*)\<(.*)$`).

The end result that I am trying to achieve is to have

`http://domain.com/<whatever>` turn into `http://domain.com/whatever`, and

`http://domain.com/a=<whatever>&b=whatever` turn into `http://domain.com/a=whatever&b=whatever`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is encoded as `%3C` and `>` is encoded as `%3E` by browsers. So have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)(?:%3C|%3E)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

This will redirect `http://domain.com/?a=<whatever>&b=whatever` to `http://domain.com/?a=whatever&b=whatever`

Comment: I could've sworn that encoding happened _after_ the .htaccess was taken into account. Good to know that this isn't the case on RewriteCond (or is it just with the query string?)

Comment: Yes i believe it is case only with query string.

Comment: Perfect answer! Learned something new today about the query string encoding timing. Thanks!