# HTACCESS - Redirect with non alphanumeric characters

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, whitespace, non-alphanumeric

I have a website linking to mine with a really badly formed URL: `http://my-example.com/<br />`. It looks like the developer of the site linking to mine has messed up their coding and has let a line break tag end up in the middle of `href` attribute of the link.

I've not had problems with redirecting URLs with non-alphanumeric characters, the only issues is the space in the `<br />`.

The Redirect line is:

```
Redirect 301 category-name/<br /> http://example.com/new-url
```

The space in the `<br />` will be mis-interpreted by the server as the delimiter between the request URL and new URL.

Is there a way I can make the space in `<br />` be treated as part of the URL, similar to how the backslash works in RegEx,  or do I need to take a different approach to this?

The url leads to a dead page, so needs to be redirected nonetheless.

I tried looking at:
[Remove Characters from URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess) and [Remove Characters from URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess) along with a few others but these don't seem to help, particularly the second not solving the issues with spaces in the URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` and then use `\s` for matching space:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "category-name/<br\s/>" http://example.com/new-url
```