# Loop over single RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

Would there be any way to continuously repeat execution of a single RewriteRule in .htaccess?

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ...

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)(?:^|&)q=[^&]*(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2

# ...
```

This rule will only be executed once before moving on to other rules. However, it could certainly match more than once:

> **Input**:        /?a=a&q=q&b=b&q=q&c=c
>   **Expected**: /?a=a&b=b&c=c
>   **Actual**:       /?a=a&b=b&q=q&c=c

The closest way to do this seems to be the `[N]` flag, but this only works if the rule is at the very top of the file. Unfortunately, this is not feasible if the rule relies on other rules being executed beforehand.

[An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13819616/3150271) suggests that it is not possible, but it never addresses the question directly.

---

To add more context, the end goal is to  essentially encode a query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

# ...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/(.+)
RewriteRule .? - [E=QUERY:%1,S=1]
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
# Repeat the next rule as many times as possible
RewriteCond %{ENV:QUERY} (.*?)&(.*)
RewriteRule .? - [E=QUERY:%1\%26%2]
RewriteRule .? /folder?query=%{ENV:QUERY}

# ...
```

This would result in the following:

> **Input**:        /folder/a&b&c
>   **Expected**: /folder?query=a%26b%26c
>   **Actual**:       /folder?query=a%26b&c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I'm still curious if there would be a general way to loop on one rule continuously in `.htaccess`.

First you should create an `index.php` in `folder/` with this content to display the various PHP variables:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Here is a generic way to loop the rules and replace each `&` by `-` [using `N` flag.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n)

```
RewriteEngine On

#   
# your other rules here
#

# recursively replace & by - and build query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:query=-?(.+))?$
RewriteRule ^(folder)/([^&]+)(?:&(.+))?$ $1/$3?query=%1-$2 [N,NC]

# **will never execute** due to previous rule looping
RewriteRule ^(folder)/(.+)$ $1/?query=$2 [NC,L,R]
```

> The `[N]` flag causes the ruleset to start over again from the top, using the result of the ruleset so far as a starting point. **Use with extreme caution, as it may result in loop**.

Comment: I appreciate the follow up, but this will still make .htaccess restart from the top of the file and test all prior conditions between each replacement of `&` (assuming that this is not at the top of the file). This seems extremely unnecessary and inefficient, so I was wondering if there was a way to continuously repeat a single rule without beginning from the top of the file after each individual replacement. If there were 500 or so `&` symbols, it would be much better to not try matching the previous rules that many times, instead just focusing on the one rule. It appears not to be possible.

Comment: By removing `L` flag you can stop all the rules to be evaluated again. See updated answer.

Comment: But, wouldn't that mean that the entire file is reevaluated every time, so the same problem exists?

Comment: I tested with your snippet, and it appears to be executed multiple times. The first runthrough skips the second rule because of the `[^&]`. It continues repeating the whole file but only matching the first rule until the second rule matches as well.

Comment: If it really wasn't executing the second rule before the first rule completely finishes, the second rule could be reduced to `^(folder)/(.+)/?$ ...`.

Comment: Check updated answer with `N` flag. Last rule will never execute because `N` rule will loop until anything is left after `/folder/`

Comment: Perfect, great idea to leave the trailing part of the string in the path itself. It would still be nice if there was a way for .htaccess to just repeat a single rule indefinitely without considering other rules, but at least this works well as a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

At least in this specific case, there does appear to be a simple answer by using the [`[B]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b):

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/(.+) /folder?query=$1 [B]
```

However, I'm still curious if there would be a general way to loop on one rule continuously in .htaccess.