# htaccess url rewrite remove comma in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to clean the look of my url, some url where the product_name parameter contains a comma its showing in url, I would like to remove that from the url if anyone knows how

```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?product_id=([^&]+)&product_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /product/%1/%2? [NE,L,R]

  RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$  deal.php?deal_id=$1&deal_name=$2   [B,NC,L]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Characters from URL with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818776/remove-characters-from-url-with-htaccess)